# Speeding up a ms access sql query from excel

Tags: sql, performance, excel, ms-access, vba

I have the code below and it seems to be taking a while to open the recordset and run the query attached (62 seconds to be exact). While 1 minute is fine, when I need to do this 13 times, it begins to take a long time to run the code.

I've debugged the code down to just the opening of the recordset taking the longest time.

My question is: Is there a method to run this faster? (i'm connecting to MS Access 2013 from Excel 2013)

Thanks in advance,

Rich

```
Sub GetUnits2()

'Declaring the necessary variables.
Dim con         As Object
Dim rs          As Object
Dim AccessFile  As String
Dim strTable    As String
Dim SQL         As String
Dim myValues()  As Variant
Dim i           As Long
Dim k           As Long
Dim j           As Integer
Dim SheetName   As String
Dim WeekNumber As Long
Dim year As Long
Dim Model1 As String
Dim Model2 As String
Dim xlrow As Integer
Dim xlcol As Integer

SheetName = "Sheet2"
Sheets(SheetName).Select

Model1 = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(3, 2).Value
Model2 = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(4, 2).Value


'Disable screen flickering.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Specify the file path of the accdb file. You can also use the full path of the file like:
AccessFile = "C:\Users\rich.wolff\Desktop\2014POSDatabase\HMKPOSDatabase2014.accdb"


On Error Resume Next
'Create the ADODB connection object.
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
'Check if the object was created.
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Connection was not created!", vbCritical, "Connection error"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Open the connection.
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & AccessFile

'Set Current Week, Year, & Starting Cell
WeekNumber = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(8, 14).Value
year = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(9, 14).Value

xlcol = 14 'Starting Column
xlrow = 11 'Starting Row


'Open Query Loop
For k = 1 To 1

 SQL = "SELECT Sum(StoreSalesData.QTY) AS Units"
 SQL = SQL & " FROM VSNConversionData INNER JOIN ([Sleepys Store List] INNER JOIN StoreSalesData ON [Sleepys Store List].[Store Code] = StoreSalesData.STR) ON VSNConversionData.VSN = StoreSalesData.VSN"
 SQL = SQL & " WHERE (((VSNConversionData.VSNStyle)='" & Model2 & "') AND ((StoreSalesData.WeekNum)=" & WeekNumber & ") AND ((StoreSalesData.Year)=" & year & ") AND ((StoreSalesData.STR) In (SELECT FloorModels2.[Source Org]"
 SQL = SQL & " FROM FloorModels2"
 SQL = SQL & " WHERE (((FloorModels2.[Source Org]) In (SELECT FloorModels2.[Source Org]"
 SQL = SQL & " FROM FloorModels2"
 SQL = SQL & " WHERE (((FloorModels2.WeekNumber)=" & WeekNumber & ") AND ((FloorModels2.Year)=" & year & ") AND ((FloorModels2.VSNStyle)='" & Model1 & "')))) AND ((FloorModels2.WeekNumber)=" & WeekNumber & ") AND ((FloorModels2.Year)=" & year & ") AND ((FloorModels2.VSNStyle)='" & Model2 & "')))));"


On Error Resume Next
'Create the ADODB recordset object.
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

'Check if the object was created.
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    MsgBox "Connection was not created!", vbCritical, "Connection error"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Set thee cursor location.
rs.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient on early  binding
rs.CursorType = 1 'adOpenKeyset on early  binding

'Open the recordset.
rs.Open SQL, con

'Redim the table that will contain the filtered data.
ReDim myValues(rs.RecordCount)


If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Dim dbcol As Integer
    dbcol = 0
    Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(xlrow, xlcol).ClearContents
    Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(xlrow, xlcol).Value = rs(dbcol).Value
Else
    rs.Close
    con.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset!", vbCritical, "No Records"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Close the recordet
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

If WeekNumber = 1 Then
    year = year - 1
    WeekNumber = 52
Else
    year = year
    WeekNumber = WeekNumber - 1
End If

' Next Column
xlcol = xlcol - 1

Next
'End Query Loop

con.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set con = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run the query from Access? I think it will make things a lot easier for us *and* you to debug and optimize such a query from Access itself and remove all the Excel 'noise'. Table structure, indexes and other information about your database are probably more relevant than this VBA code.

Comment: Takes about 9 seconds to run the query in access.

Comment: I agree with @GolezTrol -- it's hard to imagine why Excel serves as the center of this application.  The reply about 9-seconds only reinforces this perception.

Comment: I took a look at the indexing of the access database. Fixed that up. Runs MUCH quicker.

Comment: also why two sub selects? merge the second subquery within the first's where condition.

Comment: I have to sub selects because  I have a list of Stores with the products they have on different lines. 

Showroom SKU
4RU           TPRHLX
4RU           TPCTSP
4RU           TPCLSP

My goal is to derive a list of showrooms (we have 1030 of them just like 4RU, which leaves us with about 40k skus per week) where when the TPCLSP is presnt, the TPRHLX is also present. The only way I could think of this was run a query, get a list of showrooms, then run the same query in the updated showroom list. Not sure if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Have I wandered accidentally into a PHP forum?

Declare the ADODB libraries using tools:references - they will run faster, you get intellisense and a listing of all the available properties and options in the Object Browser,  *and* you gain the ability to run the query asynchronously.

That's Early-Binding, an improvement on Late-Binding.

Next, open the Recordset object with dbForwardOnly (slightly faster) and dump it into a VBA array variant with the Recordset.GetRows method: transpose the array in your code, and write it to the range.

I can see that you've made progress on optmising the SQL: try saving it as a parameter query in the database. The ADODB.Command object can open a named query, populate the parameters, and return a recordset - the query *itself*  may or may not run faster, but the lead time to parse the SQL will be significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Sub M_snb()
  c00 = "C:\Users\rich.wolff\Desktop\2014POSDatabase\HMKPOSDatabase2014.accdb"
  With Sheets("sheet2")
    sn = Array(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(4, 2), .Cells(8, 14), .Cells(9, 14)) ' model 1, model 2, weeknumber, year
  End With

  For j = 1 To 13
    c01 = "SELECT Sum(StoreSalesData.QTY) AS Units"
    c01 = c01 & " FROM VSNConversionData INNER JOIN ([Sleepys Store List] INNER JOIN StoreSalesData ON [Sleepys Store List].[Store Code] = StoreSalesData.STR) ON VSNConversionData.VSN = StoreSalesData.VSN"
    c01 = c01 & " WHERE (((VSNConversionData.VSNStyle)='" & sn(1) & "') AND ((StoreSalesData.WeekNum)=" & sn(2) & ") AND ((StoreSalesData.Year)=" & sn(3) & ") AND ((StoreSalesData.STR) In (SELECT FloorModels2.[Source Org]"
    c01 = c01 & " FROM FloorModels2"
    c01 = c01 & " WHERE (((FloorModels2.[Source Org]) In (SELECT FloorModels2.[Source Org]"
    c01 = c01 & " FROM FloorModels2"
    c01 = c01 & " WHERE (((FloorModels2.WeekNumber)=" & sn(2) & ") AND ((FloorModels2.Year)=" & sn(3) & ") AND ((FloorModels2.VSNStyle)='" & sn(0) & "')))) AND ((FloorModels2.WeekNumber)=" & sn(2) & ") AND ((FloorModels2.Year)=" & sn(3) & ") AND ((FloorModels2.VSNStyle)='" & sn(1) & "')))));"

    With CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
      .Open c01, "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & c00
      Sheets("sheets2").Cells(11, 14 + j).CopyFromRecordset .DataSource
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried this - I'm getting a "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed." error.

Comment: you might adjust this number: Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0; into e.g. Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;